# Генерация случайного числа

Tags: c++

Сделал маленькую программу, которая генерирует случайное число, и пользователю нужно его угадать.
Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void random(int zagadanoe)
{
    zagadanoe = rand() % 10 + 1;
}

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    int zagadanoe;

    int vvedennoe;

    srand(time(NULL));

    cout << "Привет. Я сгенерировал тебе случайное число от 1 до 10. Угадай какое это число." << endl;
    cout << endl;

    zagadanoe = rand() % 10 + 1;

    cout << "Введи число: ";

    cin >> vvedennoe;
    cout << endl;

    while (zagadanoe != vvedennoe)
    {
        cout << "Не правильно. Пробуй еще, я загадал тебе новое число." << endl;
        cout << endl;

        random(zagadanoe);

        cin >> vvedennoe;
    }
    cout << "Ты угадал. Правильное число было = " << zagadanoe;
}
```

Программа генерирует случайное число от 1 до 10. Задался вопросом, как мне с помощью while или как нибудь по другому реализовать количество попыток для угадывания.

И еще проблема, в while.
Когда мы неправильно вводим число, вызывается функция random(zagadanoe). Затем она генерирует случайное число (новое) идёт выход из функции, но, назад у while попадает прошлое число. Например, первое было сгенерировано 8, вызвалась функция random(zagadanoe) она сгенерировала 6, но по возвращению к while там осталась 8 (прошлое).

Расскажите, что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно, как нужно было сделать функцию random:

```
void random(int *zagadanoe)
{
    *zagadanoe = rand() % 10 + 1;
}
```

И как ее вызывать:

```
random(&zagadanoe);
```

Если в этих механизмах что-то остаётся неясным рекомендую изучать типы памяти и указатели.

Организовать количество попыток угадывания можно следюущим способом:

```
    int i = 0, attempts = 10; //i счётчик, attempts - количество попыток
    while (zagadanoe != vvedennoe && i < attempts) // используем логическое И
    //пока пользователь не отгадал и не исчерпал все попытки
    {
        i++; //в каждой итерации увеличиваем i на единицу
        cout << "Не правильно. Пробуй еще, я загадал тебе новое число." << endl;
        cout << endl;

        random(&zagadanoe); // решение проблемы с random

        cin >> vvedennoe;
    }
```

Конечно, подобное лучше реализовывать через цикл for:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < attempts && zagadanoe != vvedennoe; i++)
    {
        i++; //в каждой итерации увеличиваем i на единицу
        cout << "Не правильно. Пробуй еще, я загадал тебе новое число." << endl;
        cout << endl;

        random(&zagadanoe); // решение проблемы с random

        cin >> vvedennoe;
    }
```

Ну и... транслит зло.

Answer (score 0):

ты передаешь параметр в функцию random по значению, а нужно по ссылке, вызов твоей функции не меняет значения аргумента